# Getting the number of entries in a column in sqlite without duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running a program that stores a phone number each time that phone number calls by inserting a entry into a sqlite table called numberlogger with the phone number that called and a primary key.

I now would like to get a Count of how many individual phone numbers are in that table, meaning that even if a phone number called 5000 times, it should still only count as plus one in the count since its the same phone number.

I have tried this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM numberlogger;
```

but it adds plus one to each entry including from the same phone number, so its not what I would like.

I then tried a nested query with a group statement

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   numberlogger
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   numberlogger
               GROUP  BY phonenumber);
```

but it still counted duplicates.

Any idea of what query I can use To get a count of individual phone numbers, not counting duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Distinct` inside `Count` aggregate to avoid counting duplicate values. Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct phonenumber) FROM numberlogger;
```

It will count a phone number only once even if the same phone number called 5000 times